# Combine multiple files csv into one using awk

Tags: linux, csv, awk, merge

I want to combine two .csv files based on the unique id that exists in both files.
First file consist of 17 columns and the second one in 2 columns where in both files the first column is the same unique id.
In the to be created file 3 i would like 18 columns.
I have been trying paste

paste -d ' ' SPOOL1.csv SPOOL2.csv > MERGED.csv

but that of course does not take the unique columns into consideration.
Not proficient in awk so all help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried do anything in AWK? If yes please add your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like if the files are sorted then
`join SPOOL1 SPOOL2 > MERGED`
should get you closer if you deal with the delimiters not shown